# Why does AVR code use bit shifting

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c

In AVR programming, register bits are invariably set by left-shifting a `1` to the appropriate bit position - and they're cleared by a ones' complement of the same.

*Example:* for an ATtiny85, I might set *PORTB, b<sub>4</sub>* like this:

```
PORTB |= (1<<PB4);
```

or clear it like this:

```
PORTB &= ~(1<<PB4);
```

**My question is:** Why is it done this way? The simplest code ends up being a mess of bit-shifts. Why are bits defined as bit positions instead of masks.

For instance, the IO header for the ATtiny85 includes this:

```
#define PORTB   _SFR_IO8(0x18)
#define PB5     5
#define PB4     4
#define PB3     3
#define PB2     2
#define PB1     1
#define PB0     0
```

To me, it would be much more logical to define the bits as masks instead (like this):

```
#define PORTB   _SFR_IO8(0x18)
#define PB5     0x20
#define PB4     0x10
#define PB3     0x08
#define PB2     0x04
#define PB1     0x02
#define PB0     0x01
```

So we could do something like this:

```
// as bitmasks
PORTB |=  PB5 |  PB3 |  PB0;
PORTB &= ~PB5 & ~PB3 & ~PB0;
```

to turn bits b<sub>5</sub>, b<sub>3</sub>, and b<sub>0</sub> on and off, respectively. As opposed to:

```
// as bit-fields
PORTB |=  (1<<PB5) |  (1<<PB3) |  (1<<PB0);
PORTB &= ~(1<<PB5) & ~(1<<PB3) & ~(1<<PB0);
```

The bitmask code reads much more clearly: set bits `PB5`, `PB3`, and `PB0`. Furthermore, it would seem to save operations since the bits no longer need to be shifted.

I thought maybe it was done this way to preserve generality in order to allow porting code from an *n*-bit AVR to an *m*-bit (example 8-bit to 32-bit). But this doesn't appear to be the case, since `#include <avr/io.h>` resolves to definition files specific to the target microcontroller. Even changing targets from an 8-bit ATtiny to an 8-bit Atmega (where bit definitions change syntactically from `PBx` to `PORTBx`, for example), requires code changes.

Comment: I second this.  Even utilizing the ubiquitous `_BV(b)` instead of `(1<<b)` makes things needlessly messy.  I typically define bit mnemonics with `_BV()`, e.g. `#define ACK _BV(1)`.

Comment: Once it's realized that the compiler will interpret these as the same constant, which to use in *source code* is really a matter of preference.  In your own code do whatever you think is wisest; in modifying existing projects, stick to their traditions.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I realize that very well. I think I didn't make it clear that I fully understand the operations involved. My question solely regards readability of the resulting source code - which I would argue suffers from the way the bits are defined.

Comment: The choice is ultimately a matter of opinion - if you want to know why a particular codebase uses a particular method, you'll have to track down its authors and ask them the source of their policy.  Others can only *speculate* why they might or might not use these methods - and Stack Exchange is not a place for speculation.

Comment: "Since a bitmask approach would clearly yield more readable end-user code" - your personal opinion. I find it far clearer shifting 1's and 0's to the right place than having to guess whether several numbers being added together are bitmasks or not.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Interesting. Well, maybe I inadvertently asked an opinion-based question. Either way, there's been some good feedback. Coming from more of a (TI) DSP background (where bitmask is the norm), it just seemed like such odd syntax that I figured there was some concrete reason for it.

Comment: It's absolutely a matter of opinion. I find that creating a mask on the fly with bit-shift is more readable than assuming a constant is a bit mask.

Comment: @BlairFonville Maybe you already know this, but ARMs works exactly like you describe (with bitmasks).

Comment: @Chi No, I did not know that. Glad you pointed it out!

Answer (score 7):

> The simplest code ends up being a mess of bit-shifts. Why are bits defined as bit positions instead of masks.

No. Not at all. The shifts are only in the C source code, not in the compiled machine code. All the examples you showed can and will be resolved by the compiler at **compile time** because they are simple constant expressions.

`(1<<PB4)` is just a way to say "bit PB4".

- So it not only works, it does not create more code size.
- It makes also sense for the human programmer to name the bits by their index (e.g. 5) and not by their bit mask (e.g. 32) because this way consecutive numbers 0..7 can be used to identify the bits instead of awkward power of two (1, 2, 4, 8, .. 128).
- And there is another reason (maybe the main reason):
  The C-header files can not only be used for C-code but also for assembler source code (or assembler code inlined in C source code).
  In AVR assembler code you definitely not only want to use bit masks (which can be created from indices by bit shifting). For some AVR bit manipulation assembler instructions (e.g. SBI, CBI, BST, BLD) you have to use **bit indices as immediate operator** in their instruction op code.
  Only if you identify bits of SFRs by **indices** (not by bit mask) you can use such identifiers directly as the assembler instructions immediate operand. Otherwise you had to have two definitions for each SFR bit: one defining its bit index (which can be used e.g. as operand in aforementioned bit manipulating assembler instructions) and one defining its bit mask (which can only be used for instructions where the whole byte is manipulated).

Comment: This. Most compilers perform constant propagation as part of the optimization process.

Comment: I understand that. I’m not questioning whether it works or not. I know it does. I’m asking why the definitions are written as they are. To me it would greatly improve code readability if they were defined as masks instead of bit positions.

Comment: Most... probaly almost all. It would be a very bad compiler if it wouldn't resolve such simple constant expressions.

Comment: @Blair Fonville: See my extension of the answer. If you are more used to it it is even more readably be the programmer and it makes sense to use indices of bits instead of their bit masks (as you proposed).

Comment: I'm not sure I can agree that "PORTB |= PB4" is less readable than "PORTB |= (1<<PB4)".  In either case, the programmer rarely needs to actually know what PB4 represents - whether it equals "4" or "0x10" is transparent to programmer. In fact, its actual value is buried in a twice-mapped include file that targets the actual chip.

Comment: I don't want to claim that "PORTB |= PB4" is less readable than "PORTB |= (1<<PB4)". just that the difference is well tolerable especially if there is a good reason.

Comment: Your answer makes since, but to play the devil's advocate: there really doesn't appear to be a "good reason". It's a lot of code pollution over seemingly no gain. The <avr/io.h> definitions file could easily include a single macro to map a mask to an index. There would be no need to have "two definitions for each SFR...". The macro (in C and/or asm) wouldn't care whether 0x10 is a mask for PORTB or EEARH... either way, it's always a mask for bit 4. That would take care of the few asm calls that require an index.

Comment: I think this answer misses the point. He never talks about code efficiency or compiler. It's all about _source code_ clutter.

Comment: @Blair Fonville: there is no easy way to define such a macro. It needed to calculate the logarithm to base 2. There is no preprocessor functionality calculating the logarithm. I.e. it only could be done using a table and that, I think, would be a very bad idea.

Comment: @Curd I think a simple LUT macro would work fine. There's only 8 bit indexes (or 32, for 32-bit controllers).

Comment: @pipe: I don't talk about it because I just don't consider it as "code pollution" or "source code clutter" (or whatever you want to call it). On the contrary I think it's even useful to remind the programmer/reader that the constant he is using is a power of two (and that is done by using the shift expression).

Comment: Could you define a C macro that just enables you to use PORTB setbit(PB5); and PORTB clearbit(PB5); to clean up the source code? I'm note sure how macro expansion works...

Comment: @RJR, Blair Fonville: of course it is easily possible to define such macros BUT while using simple preprocessor defines is ok I'd avoid preprocessor macros (aka preprosessor functios) whenever possible because they can make debugging (stepping through C source code with the debugger) extremely intransparent.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps bit shifting is not the only use case for the `PB*` definitions.  Perhaps there is another use cases where where the `PB*` definitions are used directly rather than as shift amounts.  If so then I believe the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle would lead you to implement one set of defines that can be used for both use cases (like these `PB*` defines) rather than two different sets of defines that have repetitive information.

For example, I wrote an application that can take measurements from up to 8 ADC channels.  It has one interface to start a new measurement in which you can specify multiple channels via an 8-bit field, one bit for each channel.  (The measurements are performed in parallel when multiple channels are specified.) 
 Then it has another interface that returns the measurement results for an individual channel.  So one interface uses the channel number as a shift into a bit-field and the other interface uses the channel number directly.  I defined a single enumeration to cover both use cases.

```
typedef enum
{
    CHANNEL_XL_X = 0,
    CHANNEL_XL_Y = 1,
    CHANNEL_XL_Z = 2,
    CHANNEL_G_X = 3,
    CHANNEL_G_Y = 4,
    CHANNEL_G_Z = 5,
    CHANNEL_AUX1 = 6,
    CHANNEL_AUX2 = 7
} ChannelNum;

struct MeasurementResult;

void StartMeasurement(uint8_t channel_mask);
MeasurementResult ReadMeasurementResult(ChannelNum channel_num);

main
{
    ...

    StartMeasurement( (1 << CHANNEL_XL_X) | (1 << CHANNEL_XL_Y) | (1 << CHANNEL_XL_Z) );

    meas_result_x = ReadMeasurementResult(CHANNEL_XL_X);
    meas_result_y = ReadMeasurementResult(CHANNEL_XL_Y);
    meas_result_z = ReadMeasurementResult(CHANNEL_XL_Z);
}
```